# Does the compiler look for a **super** keyword in child class constructor before calling the it's base class constructor?

Tags: java, constructor

I have below classes in the same package:

```
class Moo
{
    Moo()
    {
        System.out.println("No-Arguments Base Constructor!");
    }

    Moo(int a)
    {
        System.out.println("Parameterized Base Constructor!");
    }

    public String coolMethod()
    {
        return "Wow!";
    }
}

class Zoo extends Moo
{
    Zoo()
    {
        super(10);
        System.out.println("SubClass Constructor!");
    }

    public String coolMethod()
    {
        return "Zoo Wow!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Zoo m = new Zoo();
        System.out.println(m.coolMethod());
    }
}
```

And the **Output** is like below:

```
Parameterized Base Constructor!
SubClass Constructor!
Zoo Wow!
```

What I know is, "whenever we run a program, the compiler will execute the base class default constructor before executing the child constructor".
But in this case, the parameterized constructor is getting called first (instead of default constructor).

So my question is, Does the compiler look for a **super** keyword in child class constructor before executing the base class constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong: "[...] the compiler will execute the base class *default* constructor before executing the child constructor"

Better explained: Except for type `java.lang.Object` each constructor must call another constructor at its very first statement. This might be a constructor in the same class - using `this(...)` - or a constructor in the super class - using `super(...)`.

If you excplicitely specify another constructor, then exactly that constructor will be executed. If you don't specify it, the compiler will put a call to `super()` (with no arg) automatically.

In your example

```
Zoo() {
    super(10);
    System.out.println("SubClass Constructor!");
}
```

you explicitely invoked the super class constructor with an argument. So, the no-arg constructor will not be called.

If - on the other hand - you had written

```
Zoo() {
    System.out.println("SubClass Constructor!");
}
```

then the output would have been

> No-Arguments Base Constructor!
>
> SubClass Constructor!
>
> Zoo Wow!

Keep in mind, that the compiler then had generated byte code that looks like

```
Zoo() {
    super()
    System.out.println("SubClass Constructor!");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Does the compiler look for a super keyword in child class constructor before executing the base class constructor?

Yes.

If you didn't mention any *super* related constructor, then default will invoke. Otherwise mentioned constructor invokes.

Answer (score 0):

In your case (as shown below), you are explicitely calling super with a parameter and hence super constructor is being called.

```
Zoo()
{
    super(10);
    System.out.println("SubClass Constructor!");
}
```

While if you omit `super(10);`, it will by default call `super();` i.e. constructor of parent class without any parameter although you wont see that call in the code.

Answer (score 0):

when you put `super()` it will call the constructor w/out argument of the parent class and it is also called a constructor w/out argument of the parent class when you dont declare any super() in your constructor.

so basically when you call `super(10);` where 10 is an int value so it will call your Moo constructor with an argument that accepts int.

Answer (score 0):

Since you specified a super keyword with the parameter in the child class constructor, it will go to parameterized constructor in the base class.

Otherwise the default constructor will be executed.